# Don't auto community wiki answers to questions made CW through too many edits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-wiki

I recently answered [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13357826/73226)

The OP made so many edits before I supplied my answer that the question was made CW. As a result my answer also became community wiki.

I don't see any benefit to this feature and it just disincentivises providing answers to such questions. Can this feature be removed?

**Epilogue**

BTW: I did flag this answer at the time just to see what the response would be.

> Can I get this answer un community wikified? The OP managed to make
>   the question CW by dint of editing it multiple times but I don't see
>   why my answer should be automatically penalized

And received the response

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it.

The answer in question only ever received a single upvote anyway so the effect on rep is negligible but the experience now makes me extremely unlikely to provide answers to such questions unless they happened to also be outstandingly good questions.

**Update 2**

I wasn't actually sure whether there was some technical reason why removing the CW on questions would be more troublesome than doing so on answers.

But I happened to notice the same thing occurred today on [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215664/what-to-do-when-your-edit-is-rejected-even-if-it-is-right) and the auto wiki was successfully removed so that doesn't appear to be a barrier.

Comment: I think more than a handful of us hate auto-wiki...

Comment: That question bears so little relation to the original it's ridiculous. The OP has been using it like a _gasp_ forum.

Comment: Do you want to remove auto-wikification entirely, or just change it so that it won't affect answers to a converted question?

Comment: @MadScientist - This feature request is to change it so that it won't affect answers to a converted question. I wouldn't be averse to removing it entirely but I see that it does have some value in preventing people abusing the system by continually bumping their question. Not sure how that could be prevented otherwise. maybe a rep penalty for every edit after some threshold.

Comment: I think auto-wiki should be completely removed. From what I've seen, there are ***many many many*** more false positives than actual cases of abuse. I've seen far too many great posts fall victim to auto-wiki. If there is abusive-bumping, someone will see it and flag it. If anything just replace auto-wiki with auto-flags.

Comment: @Mysticial: Good idea. We're already alerted to users hitting the daily edit rate limit by auto-flags, so I don't see any harm in using auto-flags for too many edits on the same post as well.

Comment: If you're here *only* for the rep maybe it's not the place for you. It should be a nice bonus, not the sole purpose that you post.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I'm not here **only** for the rep and I already stated that if the question was particularly interesting I might make an exception. Fairly frequently I hit the rep cap anyway and it would make no practical difference. Just if the site is to be gamified I want the rules to be fair and make sense. I doubt that I am the only person who regards it as a disincentive and may move onto another question. Pretending otherwise is disingenuous. This is a real negative consequence of the current policy.

Comment: @Martin I would consider this as very minor nuisance especially having more than enough rep already. Your sentence "but the experience now makes me extremely unlikely to provide answers to such questions" triggered my original comment here.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I knew someone would comment on that!

Comment: As posted in a similar thread, the cure (auto-wiki) is worse than the disease (too much bumping).  We should either get to the root of the problem and **stop having things be bumped by the 3rd etc. edit of the day (then auto-wiki by owner's edits alone can go away)**, or we should make auto-wiki **reversible by the questioner with no great hoops to jump through** (i.e. "but found no evidence to support it" should not be a reason not to do it.  The burden of evidence should lie with keeping it wiki!)

Comment: FWIW at the question you recently referred, it looks like mod manually removed CW separately from question (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/215664/revisions) and from the answer (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/215666/revisions)

Comment: @gnat - Ah, thanks, so it is slightly more work then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We took a bit of an alternate route here. Rather than changing how answer conversion works, we instead changed it so that **posts are no longer converted automatically to community wiki for any reason**. As such, if a post receives too many edits, then that won't affect your answer by proxy.

The only way for a question to become community wiki, going forward, is by a moderator specifically converting it so. The instances for this should be exceedingly rare, and in general something reached by community consensus on the site's meta. The conversion of attached answers will persist, but the permanence of this status should be handled in such communications.

Comment: Excellent idea!