# Tag score incorrectly lowered, tag badge lost

Tags: discussion, support, tag-badges, tag-score

I had more than 100 points on [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) at SO, and bronze badge. Suddenly today I have only 90 pts on the tag and badge is lost! This must be a bug, because:

- when I [filter my answers under this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a684229%20%5Balgorithm%5D%20is%3aanswer), the sum of the scores is 103! And the newest scored answer is from last year.
- Data Explorer is from June 25th and it is still correct: see:

  - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/122332/my-score-on-the-algorithm-tag
  - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/122334/my-answers-on-the-algorithm-tag

My reputation is intact (or at least I have not observed lowering of it).

Comment: You forgot to add wiki:no to your search filter. The edit on [that particular (filtered out) answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770945/largest-rectangular-sub-matrix-with-the-same-number/7773870#7773870) made it community wiki.

Comment: @J.Steen thanks! WTF! How did it happen that [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7773870/684229) is community wiki now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Largest rectangular sub matrix with the same number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770945/largest-rectangular-sub-matrix-with-the-same-number/7773870#7773870) was converted to a community wiki because you edited it too many times.

[image]

Since Community wiki's don't count towards tag badges and that question was worth 13 upvotes. Your 103 went down by 13 to 90. So the amount is correct.

You might be able uncommunity wiki it by flagging your question for moderator attention and explaining you want it undone.

According to [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)

> A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1)
>   and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on answers under that specific
>   tag (votes on questions do not count). **As well, posts which are in
>   community wiki status or that have been deleted do not count towards
>   your tag score.** Tag scores are only recalculated once daily, at
>   03:00 UTC.

Comment: I always thought that future upvotes don't count if something turns into CW.

Comment: OK thanks... this is really not very pleasant. I only tried to improve my post and I am punished?? This is demotivating... OK at least I can flag it for moderator attention, thanks.

Comment: @juergend http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work does not seem to imply that.

Comment: @Tomas Some of your edits are 1 character edits. You are supposed to make substantial edits not lots of small ones. I believe the reason it happen is to stop lots of small edits

Comment: FDinoff this argument is not valid. I am only supposed to keep my post as good as I can.

Comment: @Tomas http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183918/what-is-the-reason-behind-auto-convertion-to-community-wiki-after-5-10-edits Might give some insight if it doesn't search around for other posts.

Comment: @Tomas You are encouraged to make changes to keep the answer updated, but as has been mentioned, the purpose is to prevent someone from continually bumping the post with irrelevant edits.  Your problem started is you made 8 edits within the first 12 hours of the post's life, many of which were extremely minor.

Comment: @Tomas IIRC, diamond mods can undo automatic CW, but you need to be able to justify why your numerous edits were necessary.  If you think you can justify it, flag your answer with a custom flag and see if you can explain in less than 500 characters.  If the mod things it is justified, they might undo the CW.

Comment: It would be nice if you could mark an edit as "minor" that would prevent the post from being bumped but also not count towards the edit count for community wiki conversion.

Comment: Well thanks to some "action from above", my post was converted back. But I see it will need an update soon (I found better algorithm). Will it be converted to CW automatically again?

Comment: @Tomas I would guess no. But I don't really know