# What to do when your edit is rejected, even if it is right

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

I notice that sometimes we do editing of a question and the reviewer rejects the edit request in a second, even though we know that the editing is done by us is quite right (I know they have much knowledge).

So what we can do when the reviewer rejects our editing and we know it is right?

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3764919) edit of mine that was rejected.

Comment: Hard to advise in general. Do you have a specific example you can share? I assume you're talking about a suggested edit you made, which was rejected? Can you link to the review?

Comment: @Duncan : http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3767316

Comment: Who's this "we" you're talking about?

Comment: That edit was rejected with the wrong reason IMO, it should have been rejected for being *too minor*.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would have rejected that edit. All you've done is remove some whitespace from the end of a code line. For that you should get 2 reputation points? Although I would have chosen the "too minor" rejection reason.

Comment: @AlE. : Here "WE" refer for some users who think the same.

Comment: A better example might have been [this suggested edit that you made](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3764919).

Comment: In the example provided by me I explain that we need some work to do beside modify ore_config_data table..
urls are also store in log_url table and magento which support caching initially fetch data from cache..

Comment: @Duncan: That edit was rightly rejected, too. Edits are supposed to make posts better, and that one introduces spelling errors and make a sentence ungrammatical. It could possibly have been "improved", but I'm not sure that the supplemental information it adds is even really that valuable. A comment would have been better.

Comment: Also the edit comment doesn't have anything to do with the actual edit.

Comment: there are 2 positive vote too

Comment: @AlE. Yup, I completely agree. I just felt that was an example that perhaps the OP was truly talking about!

Comment: related: [Editing Philosophy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194728/editing-philosophy) "Just read a couple MSO posts about editing guidelines, after seeing my edit getting rejected..."

Comment: @ALL : One more thing I noticed that people who rejected my code (suggest edit) even don't know "M" of Magento.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One mistake you're making is that you're changing the content of other people's answers.

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3764919) should have been left as a comment. That puts your name on it, and leaves it up to the author of the answer to include it or not.  Same thing in [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3620977).

[This suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3767316) doesn't seem to be adding anything to the answer.  The edit comment probably should have been a plain comment.

[This suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3763331) does clarify slightly, but it's not really needed.  Your edit comment also doesn't make sense in the context of your edit.

Make sure your edits are *improving* answers, but *without changing their meaning*.  If you want to add something you need to do that in a comment or in a complete answer of your own.  Also make sure your edit comment matches what you changed in the answer. Some people will smell something wrong and reject if these two don't match up, and others will only read the edit comment and reject if it indicates that you're changing something you shouldn't.  All of these are valid reasons to reject.  Stack Overflow is a collaboratively edited site, but when editing someone else's words, you need to be careful that you don't change their meaning.

Comment: thats I am looking for

Comment: you provide me a better answer while others are...

Comment: @urfusion let me finish that sentence for you. ... while others are just commenting. Comments are not the same as answers, and this is a great example of it.

Comment: @KateGregory : true my friend.. :)

Comment: dont vote down immediately try to provide batter answers..
by doing this new users doesn't hesitate in posting answers and questions...